# I upgraded from rails rails (4.1.8) to rails '4.2.5.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I changed in the Gemfile rails “4.1.8’ and added rails ‘4.2.5.1’ and renamed the Gemlock file so I then ran bundle install and bundle update.
rails did upgrade and installed other the other dependencies...but now can’t run the rails s…..see the below errors.  The issues appears to be some mis configurations.

```
C:\Sites\scheduleio>rails s
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.2.5.1 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
C:/Sites/scheduleio/config/initializers/ssl_configuration.rb:5: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER
Exiting
```

[Here is the link to the full errors I am getting...](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1imhmTqW7fDglnilpUT8Ov8iAIklGm984JHIgfkQagEY/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Please add a code snippet or error trace to the question body, not in the __google docs__

Comment: I added the link to the GDoc because the error code and trace data is more than the allowed characters in this text box

Answer (score 0):

`initializers/ssl_configuration.rb:5: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER` ?

this might be the cause of your error. Maybe taking this constant out or renaming it to something else

Comment: I have the SSL configuration set to nothing..since i am working in development stage...prior to upgrading getting the errors after the SSL initializes....any help ...I really, really appreciate it...

Comment: Any help or suggestions would be great...or should I downgrade back to the previous rails 4.1.8 and what is the best and practice to down grade back down....thanks a ton!!!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone..I just needed to update my version of rails.